# Can't change options on Bootstrap 5 toast

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to use Bootstrap 5, but I'm struggling a lot with toasts. I want to change the default delay to 5 seconds. [The docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/toasts/#options) say you can add a data attribute, so that's what I did:

```
    <div id="successToast" class="toast d-flex align-items-center text-white bg-primary border-0" role="alert"
    aria-live="assertive" aria-atomic="true" data-bs-delay="5000">
    <div class="toast-body">
      Action completed successfully.
    </div>
    <button type="button" class="btn-close btn-close-white ms-auto me-2" data-bs-dismiss="toast"
      aria-label="Close"></button>
  </div>

  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/5.0.0-alpha1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    var toastElList = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.toast'))
    var toastList = toastElList.map(function (toastEl) {
      // Creates an array of toasts (it only initializes them)
      return new bootstrap.Toast(toastEl) // No need for options; use the default options
    });
    var successToast = toastList[0];
  </script>
```

However, this didn't affect the delay in any way and I'm not seeing any errors. It mentions you can pass the value via JS as well so I tried `successToast.show({ delay: "5000" });` but this also failed. What am I missing here?

Comment: so according to the docs you linked 5000 is the default delay. Hence why you probably aren't seeing any affect. Have you tried upping the delay to 10,000?

Comment: It's appearing for half a second right now

Comment: Hmm are you sure there is no other code possibly setting that delay elsewhere? I would try raising the delay really high just to see if it has any affect at all. If it doesn't I'd bet there may be something else overwriting your delay somewhere.

Comment: I tried setting it really high, yeah it's not working but I don't set it anywhere else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    <div id="successToast" class="toast d-flex align-items-center text-white bg-primary border-0" role="alert"
    aria-live="assertive" aria-atomic="true">
    <div class="toast-body">
      Action completed successfully.
    </div>
    <button type="button" class="btn-close btn-close-white ms-auto me-2" data-bs-dismiss="toast"
      aria-label="Close"></button>
  </div>

  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/5.0.0-alpha1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    var toastElList = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.toast'))
    var toastList = toastElList.map(function (toastEl) {
      // Creates an array of toasts (it only initializes them)
      return new bootstrap.Toast(toastEl, {
                    animation: true,
                    autohide: true,
                    delay: 5000,
                })
    });
    var successToast = toastList[0];
  </script>
```

I could not get the data attribute to work either but this is how you can do it with the options parameter.